# C# selenium - SetUp - test name

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit

Trying to get the name of the test in SetUp, I get: "AdhocTestMethod"...

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUpFunc()
{
    var asd = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
}

[Test(Description = "testingSetup")]
public void TestName123()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(false);
}
```

I'm using NUnit 2.6.3

Answer (score 0):

A new answer has just been posted regarding "AdhocTestMethod" search for [customattribute adhoctestmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=customattribute+adhoctestmethod)

Answer (score -1):

I think you've got some problem with your setup. It works fine for me.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUpFunc()
        {
            var asd = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
            Console.WriteLine($"Setup: {asd}");
        }

        [Test(Description = "testingSetup")]
        public void TestName123()
        {
            var asd = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
            Console.WriteLine($"Test: {asd}");
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints

```
Setup: TestName123
Test: TestName123
```

I have NUnit 2.6.3 and NUnitTestAdapter 2.1.1 installed.